# Mock method of object and return object value depend of method param

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

There is the way to mock method and return value depend of method argument? I need this to simulate container and get service. I try to do this by:

```
$container = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(Container::class)
        ->getMock();

$container
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('logger')
        ->willReturn($this->loggerMock)//this is logger object
    ;
$container->expects($this->any())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('database')
        ->will($this->returnValue(self::$pdo));//database object

$this->dataProviderFactory = new DataProviderFactory($container);
```

And when I call this: print_r($container->get('logger')); should have Logger object.

But this doesn't work. I got error below:

Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked zero or more times

```
Parameter 0 for invocation Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::get('logger', 1) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :'database'
Actual   :'logger'
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but are you sure you need your factory to be dependent on the entire container?  Might be better to inject just the services it needs like the logger and the database connection.  And it makes testing a bit easier.

Comment: Right now I can not do this in way that you suggest because 
due from structure of the application that I develop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a callback function to act on the argument passed to the method at runtime.

Try the following:

```
$container = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(Container::class)
    ->getMock();

$container
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($arg) {
        $map = [
            'logger'   => $this->loggerMock,
            'database' => $this->returnValue(self::$pdo)
        ];
        return $map[$arg];
    }))
;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need :)